# fsum for numpy.arrays, stable summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a number of multidimensional `numpy.array`s with small values
that I need to add up with little numerical error. For `float`s, there is [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) (with its implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d267006f18592165ed97e0a9c2494d3bce25fc2b/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1087)), which has always served me well. [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) isn't stable enough.

How can I get a stable summation for `numpy.array`s?

---

*Background*

This is for [the quadpy package](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy). The arrays of small values are the evaluations of a function at specific points of (many) intervals, times their weights. The sum of these is an approximation of the integral of said function over the intervals.

Comment: Why wouldn't `numpy.sum` or `your_array.sum()` suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `numpy.sum` isn't stable enough for me. I guess it's just adding the (small) values one after another, so in the end, when large and small number are added, information is lost.

Comment: I believe [`numpy.sum` uses pairwise summation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685), so it's better than a naive sum, but if you're looking for more than that, NumPy doesn't provide it. If your NumPy predates the pairwise summation change, updating may help.

Comment: Looks like [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2448) might be useful, although it says that NumPy doesn't implement any more accurate summation like `math.fsum`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright then, I've implemented [accupy](https://github.com/nschloe/accupy/) which gives a few stable summation algorithms.

Here's a quick and dirty implementation of [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) for numpy arrays. Notice, however, that it is not not very accurate for ill-conditioned sums.

```
def kahan_sum(a, axis=0):
    '''Kahan summation of the numpy array along an axis.
    '''
    s = numpy.zeros(a.shape[:axis] + a.shape[axis+1:])
    c = numpy.zeros(s.shape)
    for i in range(a.shape[axis]):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817610/353337
        y = a[(slice(None),) * axis + (i,)] - c
        t = s + y
        c = (t - s) - y
        s = t.copy()
    return s
```

It does the job, but it's slow because it's Python-looping over the `axis`-th dimension.