# get the i-th slice of the k-th dimension in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `n`-dimensional numpy array, and I'd like to get the `i`-th slice of the `k`-th dimension. There must be something better than

```
# ... 
elif k == 5:
    b = a[:, :, :, :, :, i, ...]
# ...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
b = a[(slice(None),) * k + (i,)]
```

Construct the indexing tuple manually.

As documented in the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings), an expression of the form

```
a[:, :, :, :, :, i]
```

is converted to

```
a[(slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), i)]
```

We can achieve the same effect by building that tuple directly instead of using slicing notation. (There's the minor caveat that building the tuple directly produces `a[(i,)]` instead of `a[i]` for `k=0`, but NumPy handles these the same for scalar `i`.)

Comment: Whoaw. I'll happily copy-&-paste this, but a link to documentation would perhaps still be useful.

Comment: slice notation, e.g. `a[<something>]` is just syntactic sugar for a call to `__getitem__` passing it a tuple, in this case, a tuple of slice objects (the `:` notation being syntactic suger for a `slice` object)

Comment: You could also spell that `b[np.index_exp[:] * k + np.index_exp[i]]`, which is possibly a little more readable

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if it will work for k dim but it does for 2 dim

```
a.take(i,axis=k)
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of creating a copy instead of a view.

Comment: @user2357112: Huh, that's a little surprising

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to be able to programmatically create the tuple `:, :, :, :, :, i, ...` in order to pass it in as the index of `a`. Unfortunately, you cannot simply use ordinary tuple multiplication on the colon operator directly (i.e., `(:,) * k` won't work to generate a tuple of `k` colon operators). You can, however, get an instance of a "colon slice" by using `colon = slice(None)`. You could then do `b = a[(colon,) * k + (i,)]`, which would effectively index `a` at the `i`th column of the `k`th dimension.

Wrapping this up in a function, you'd get:

```
def nDimSlice(a, k, i):
    colon = slice(None)
    return a[(colon,) * k + (i,)]
```

Comment: extra slices after `i` are unnecessary as far as numpy is concerned

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, I was unaware!

Comment: This answer was really helpful! In case anyone is wondering, to extract N slices on that index just replace ```(i,)``` with ```(slice(0, n, 1),)```

Answer (score 2):

here is a late entry that can handle negative axis arguments without having to know the shape of its operand beforehand:

```
def put_at(inds, axis=-1, slc=(slice(None),)):
    return (axis<0)*(Ellipsis,) + axis*slc + (inds,) + (-1-axis)*slc
```

To be used as in

```
a[put_at(ind_list,axis=axis)]
```

`ind_list` can be a scalar as in your case or something more interesting as well.

Copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656930/numpy-assignment-like-numpy-take/42657219#comment72441626_42657219) comment of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this approach would create an entire copy of the array*, but I would take a slice of the transposed matrix in order to get the kth axis:

```
import numpy as np

def get_slice(arr, k, i):
    if k >= arr.ndim: #we need at least k dimensions (0 indexed)
        raise ValueError("arr is of lower dimension than {}".format(k))

    axes_reorder = list(range(arr.ndim)) #order of axes for transpose
    axes_reorder.remove(k) #remove original position of k
    axes_reorder.insert(0,k) #insert k at beginning of order

    return arr.transpose(axes_reorder)[i] #k is first axis now
```

This also has the added bonus of easier checking of the number of dimensions before trying the slice.

* according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), a memory view is created whenever possible.