# Write python functions to operate over arbitrary axes

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I've been struggling with this problem in various guises for a long time, and never managed to find a good solution.

Basically if I want to write a function that performs an operation over a given, but arbitrary axis of an arbitrary rank array, in the style of (for example) np.mean(A,axis=some_axis), I have no idea in general how to do this.

The issue always seems to come down to the inflexibility of the slicing syntax; if I want to access the ith slice on the 3rd index, I can use A[:,:,i], but I can't generalise this to the nth index.

Comment: Expanding on @hpaulj's first suggestion, maybe unexpectedly the result after  swapaxes->some operation creating new array->swapaxes of new array  is often contiguous, see for example [ħere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861800/7207392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` functions use several approaches to do this:

- transpose axes to move the target axis to a known position, usually first or last; and if needed transpose the result
- reshape (along with transpose) to reduce the problem simpler dimensions.  If your focus is on the n'th dimension, it might not matter where the (:n) dimension are flattened or not.  They are just 'going along for the ride'.
- construct an indexing tuple.  `idx = (slice(None), slice(None), j); A[idx]` is the equivalent of `A[:,:,j]`.  Start with a list or array of the right size, fill with slices, fiddle with it, and then convert to a tuple (tuples are immutable).
- Construct indices with `indexing_tricks` tools like `np.r_`, `np.s_` etc.

Study code that provides for axes.  Compiled `ufuncs` won't help, but functions like `tensordot`, `take_along_axis`, `apply_along_axis`, `np.cross` are written in Python, and use one or more of these tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generalize this. In fact, the example `numpy.mean(a, axis=axis_index)` is good to look at in this case. Even in numpy, which is written mostly in C, loops through the axis indexs to know where to compute the mean. Have a look at [`reduction.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/src/umath/reduction.c) which is in the core of `numpy.mean`. Even though they format the data in an advantegous manner before performing operations, to loop through all the axis with your `axis_index` is always required.